# df.value.apply returns NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns (time and pressure).

```
timestep value
    0    393
    1    389
    2    402
    3    408
    4    413
    5    463
    6    471
    7    488
    8    422
    9    404
    10   370
```

I first need to find the frequency of each pressure value and rank them `df['freq_rank']` which works fine, but when I am trying to mask the dataframe by comparing the column against count value & find interval difference, I am getting NaN results..

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.pylab import *
import re
import pylab
from pylab import *
import datetime
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot

df = pd.read_csv('copy.csv')
dataset = np.loadtxt(df, delimiter=";")
df.columns = ["Timestamp", "Pressure"]

## Timestep as int
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestep':np.arange(3284), 'value': df.Pressure})

## Rank of the frequency of each value in the df
vcs = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(df.value.value_counts().index)}
df['freq_rank'] = df.value.apply(vcs.get)
print(df.freq_rank)


>>Output:
>>0    131
>>1    235
>>2     99
>>3     99
>>4    101
>>5    101
>>6    131
>>7     79
>>8     79



## Find most frequent value
count = df['value'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=[False]).nlargest(10).index.values[0] 

## Mask the DF by comparing the column against count value & find interval diff.
x = df.loc[df['value'] == count, 'timestep'].diff()
print(x)

>>Output:
>>50        1.0
>>112      62.0
>>215     103.0
>>265      50.0
>>276      11.0
>>277       1.0
>>278       1.0
>>318      40.0
>>366      48.0
>>367       1.0
>>368       1.0
>>372       4.0

df['freq'] = df.value.apply(x.get)
print(df.freq)

>>Output:
>>0    NaN
>>1    NaN
>>2    NaN
>>3    NaN
>>4    NaN
>>5    NaN
>>6    NaN
>>7    NaN
>>8    NaN
```

I don't understand why `print(x)` returns the right output and `print(df['freq'])` returns NaN.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please? See [how to create good reproducible pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: What further information do you need? I have also included a piece of my dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with the last statement `df['freq'] = df.value.apply(x.get)`

If you just want to copy the `x` to the new column `df['freq']` you can just:

`df['freq'] = x`

Then `print(df.freq)` will give you the same results as your `print(x)` statement.

---

**Update**:
Your problem is with the indicies. `df` only has index values from 0-10 where as your `x` has 50, 112, 215...
When assigning to df, only values that has an existing index is added.

Comment: I have tried that. Even if I do `df['freq'] = x`,  when I try `print(df)` or `print(df.freq)` I still see NaN values

Comment: What does `print(x)` give you?

Comment: You can see that in the question

Comment: See my answers update. I think the problem is with the index.

Comment: You're right, that's the problem. But how can I solve it?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve I guess. You can use the `reset_index` function to make the index of `x` match `df`, but that would assign the values from `x` to just the first 10 values of `df`. You can also remove the `nlargest(10)` function and get all the values, for all the indices of `df`.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to create a column in my df, called 'freq' , the same way i created columns 'value','timestep' and 'freq_rank'. And every time I run df, to be able to see these 4 columns. The `nlargest(10)` i need it in order to find the most frequent values.

Comment: You're only calculating the frequency for the 10 largest frequencies, so only 10 rows in your dataframe are going to have values in the `freq` column. If you need the frequency to be calculated for all rows in the dataframe you need to remove the `nlargest(10)` function call.

Comment: But if I remove the `nlargest(10)`, then I will not be able to find the most frequent value. I changed it to  `nlargest()`, and the result is still NaN

Comment: `nlargest()` defaults to 5 so removing the argument it won't change anything. Remove the function call all together and then select the top frequencies once all the frequencies has been added to the dataframe. `df['freq'].nlargest(10)`.